# Does xdebug only work on a local webserver?

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I have a webserver running in the local network of my company. I installed xdebug on it.

Now I want to use my netbeans on my local computer to debug my website which runs on this local webserver.

Is this even possible, or does xdebug only work if netbeans is running on the pc/server where the webserver is running?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my question... I just had to enter the IP Adresse of my PC to the **php.ini** under `xdebug.remote_host`.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension='/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xdebug.so'
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.1.121"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = '/var/log'
```

Don't forget to restart your webserver.

Comment: This way nobody else can debug in the shared server. Perhaps it's better to use xdebug.remote_connect_back.

Comment: Do you mean instead of `xdebug.remote_host`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I tried it, now I get `Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)` and nothing happens...

Comment: I found this answer https://serverfault.com/a/474490/470060 which claims that you can just add multiple hosts separated by commas.

Comment: That's interesting. [Documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host) doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I tested it and it seems to work, at least I can still connect to it if there are multiple Ip Adresses in the field, but I did not tested it with another IP Adress